# C++ count functional words occurrence

Tags: c++, string, text

I'm trying to count occurrences of specific words from a text file, the problem is that when my code is reading the file - it is reading it with white-space delimiters but some of the words i want to count are "2 word words" for example "out from"

additional to this there is a second problem and that is the words like "aren't" and "don't" - my code seem to ignore this words even when i put them with backslash in the map - my guess is that it is getting ignored in the process of reading it from the file for some reason

the end outcome that i am looking for is the frequency of the words that i am searching for.

```
std::list<std::string> Fwords = {
"a","abroad","as far as","ahead of"};

        // Begin reading from file:
        std::ifstream fileStream(fileName);

        // Check if we've opened the file (as we should have).
        if (fileStream.is_open())
            while (fileStream.good())
            {
                // Store the next word in the file in a local variable.
                std::string word;
                fileStream >> word;
                std::cout << "This is the word: " << word << endl;

                if (std::find(std::begin(Fwords), std::end(Fwords), word) != std::end(Fwords))
                    wordsCount[word]++;
            }
```

input:

```
 "ahead of me as far as abroad me"
```

this would be the expected output:

```
abroad:1
ahead of:1
as far as:1
```

Comment: So you are saying "as far as" should be treated as a single word ?

Comment: Can you please make a [mcve]? We dont need to see all the words you want to count

Comment: @LogicStuff, he can, it's just a no-op.

Comment: Use `std::regex_search` if you just want to get the job done.

Comment: Are your entries actually unique? So what I mean, do you have detect `"out from"`, `"out"`and `"from"` all separately? Probably @LogicStuff's proposal seems most appropriate for now.

Comment: Since the stream extraction operator will stop reading a word at `whitespace`, then you will never detect strings such as `as far as`. You need to read the entire file into a string and then iterate over `Fwords` searching for each one in the read-from-file string until each "word" is not found in said string.

Comment: @LogicStuff well i didn't even thought about utilizing regex, this would be the answer to my problem.. thanks

Comment: @tobi303 i hope that i adjusted to an acceptable formatting example

Comment: @DanielShapira it is far more readable now

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work. Your problem is that you're reading one word at a time from the *file*. No amount of backslashing or manipulating the list / map of words will fix that.

But how are you supposed to know how many words to read? You don't—it'll have to be trial and error.

One way to "brute force" this, considering your level of programming, would be to add an `else` case to

```
if (std::find(std::begin(Fwords), std::end(Fwords), word) != std::end(Fwords))
{
    // ...
}
```

in which you check for words in the map that *begin* with the word from the file, *e.g.* "as," but with a space, so the search is for `as` . If one or more matches are found, then it's time to read another word from the file, *e.g.* "as far." This should be put in a loop (or a function called in a loop) so that the search for `as far`  and reading another word "as" happens automatically. Upon successfully finding `as far as`, you're done. You're also done upon failure to find `as` , `as far` , or `as far as`, *i.e.* if you don't have these in your map, in which case, you want to run a `for` loop through each word to check if they are words by themselves, and increase their count if so. In this endeavor, you'll realize that you need the same code as your original code; so it'd be smart to factor it out into a function as well.